# How to send e-mails using utf-8?

Tags: emails, plugin-freeform

does anyone know if you can send emails using utf-8 instead of ascii in CraftCMS 2?

I am using the Freeform plugin to send entries from a "Contact Us" form to a CRM that needs to receive the e-mails in utf-8 but they are coming in as ASCII. Is there a way to change this in either the plugin or in Craft?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Craft 2 uses [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) for its email sending library.

It does have a public [CharSet](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L47) property that Craft [explicitly sets](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop-v2/src/services/EmailService.php#L286) to `UTF-8` when sending emails.

The problem is, they have logic that overwrites our `UTF-8` value in certain circumstances... namely when no 8-bit characters are involved in the body setting it to `us-ascii`: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L2453-L2458

Not sure of a good resolution as this seems like undesired behavior in the PHPMailer library to me.

FWIW, the upcoming Craft 3 has ditched PHPMailer in favor of [Swift Mailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/) where it is much more customizable.

Comment: Thank you, that's what we kind of figured after conducting a few tests, and hoping for a work around that would help our client until our Ducks are in a row for the update to Craft 3. For now we are hiding a an UTF-8 character in the form to trick the mailer into sending the form in the charset we want. Would just deleting that logic break everything?

Comment: Changing any of the core files would run the risk of them being overwritten in the future on an auto/manual update.  Not sure what other  runtime implication deleting that code might have.

Comment: Thank you Brad! In the end we added an random Ü to the end of the outgoing e-mail template that seemed to do the trick. Weird and hackey but I like to think of it as an extra happy smiley face for those hardworking customer service reps who have to read the submissions. Once we upgrade to Craft 3 we will look into more sophisticated options.  Your insight is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> does anyone know if you can send emails using utf-8 instead of ascii in CraftCMS 2?

```
$message = craft()->templates->render('path/to/file/', $someVariables);

$email = new EmailModel();

$email->fromEmail = $adminEmail;
$email->replyTo = $adminEmail;
$email->sender = $adminEmail;
$email->fromName = craft()->getSiteName();
$email->toEmail = $mail;    
$email->subject = $subject;
$email->htmlBody = $message;  // <-- this is html and it will be send as utf8

craft()->email->sendEmail($email);
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunetly this won't work, i'm not writing a plug in. When Craft sends an e-mail it seems to either send it as a charset ASCII or UTF-8 based on the characters used.  If I add an ø  is sends the e-mail as UTF-8, if I don't it switches to ASCII. I'm trying to figure out how to change this to send the e-mail as UTF-8 as a default.